# How do I get the process id of the calling process in erlang?

Tags: erlang

A took a look at http://erlang.org/doc/apps/inets/http_client.html and found the following:

> An ordinary asynchronous request. The result will be sent to the calling process on the form {http, {ReqestId, Result}}
>
> ```
>       5 > {ok, RequestId} =
>       http:request(get, {"http://www.erlang.org", []}, [], [{sync, false}]).
> ```
>
> In this case the calling process is the shell, so we receive the result.
>
> ```
>       6 >  receive {http, {RequestId, Result}} -> ok after 500 -> error end.
>       ok
> ```

http:request passes a message to me after calling it that way, but how does it know my process id? As far as I understand, http:request has to do "Pid ! {http, {RequestId, Result}" to send the result to me, but where does it know the value of Pid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the definition of the #request{} record (in httpc_internal.hrl), you will see that there is a field called from. It contains the caller's pid; that's how the server will be able to send a message to the caller later.

Looking at the source code of http module you will see that your call will eventually reach the handle_request function, where the from field is set to self().

Answer (score 2):

You don't -- the calling process has to supply its Pid if it wants a reply.  Do something like

```
Server ! {self(), arguments}
```

and then the first element of the tuple is the return address.